# public Modbus server

Tags: server, modbus, modbus-tcp

I've been programming a Modbus Client through TCP and I think I'm finally done but I'd like to test it in real life scenarios and that's why I'm coming here:

¿Is there any Modbus Server available online? I mean, any kind of modbus server even though it servers only trash bytes is OK.

¿Any ideas?

Comment: try [modbus.online](http://modbus.online/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use the Modbus Simulator from the following link.
http://www.plcsimulator.org/
It is free.

Other than that, you can also use Docklight.
Docklight is a more powerful simulator.
It can be used to simulate all sort of serial and TCP simulation.
http://docklight.de/

Comment: thank you; I was finally able to simulate as I wished that way.

Comment: No problem =) @MiquelColl

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any public servers. However, why don't you test your client against a local simulator, maybe this one? http://www.plcsimulator.org/Home